# java.lang.annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath

I recently changed the package of a project in Eclipse, and doing this appears to have caused problems with the build path.

I have an annotation called PlaceholderDocumentation, seen below

```java
package com.projectjhs.forum.api.placeholders;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PlaceholderDocumentation {
    String name();

    String description();
}
```

The import `import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE` gives me the error `The import java.lang.annotation.ElementType cannot be resolved`. I also have an error in the Problems list that says

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.annotation.ElementType. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

I haven't been able to find anything related to this issue anywhere else.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: This works fine for me in the current Eclipse and Java without any problems. Can you reproduce it in the current Eclipse and Java in a new project (might be something with your dependencies)?

Comment: @howlger I created a new project, and I still got the errors above.

Comment: Have you tried with the current Eclipse without additional plugins? If so, your Java installation is broken.